# DAX : How to count the number of specific categorie based on an date column and ID column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I meet some issue when creating a measure on dax
My dataset contains data  on call center , like this :

[image]

The field STAT is "0" for call without answer and "1" for call with answer(picking up)
I want to count the number of "0" based on DATE column and ID column (we can have many calls with the same ID on the same DATE)
In our case i want the count of these rows :
[image]

The count will be 4 and i want the count per DATE and ID
I want to add a filter on the ID and when i select a specific ID , i want the table to show only one of the 4 rows and the count

This is what i try
te =
VAR we =
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(DATA),
DATA[STAT]="0"
)

VAR wt =
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(DATA),
DATA[STAT]="1"
)
RETURN
we - wt

But this formula doesn't take THE ID and DATE in consideration

I think everything is clear
can you please help me

Kind regards

Comment: Re "*But this formula doesn't take THE ID and DATE in consideration*", not sure I understand: that measure will respond to any slicers/filters based on the ID and DATE columns. Suggest you give some specific examples together with expected results. And post copiable data, not pictures.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:** Create a new **Date_new** column excluding the itme stamp and contains only DD/MM/YYYY.

**Step-2:** create this below measure-

```
count_zero = 
calculate(
    count(your_table_name[STAT],
    filter(
        allexcept(your_table_name, your_table_name[id]),
        //your_table_name[STAT] = 0
        max(your_table_name[STAT]) = 0
    )
)
```

**Step-3:** Add a table visual with column/Measure - id, date_new & count_zero.

**Step-4:** Add the filter pane with id

This should give you the expected output.

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't match what am looking for
Your measure gives me the same output like this formula :

we = 
        CALCULATE(
                  COUNTROWS(DATA), 
                  DATA[STAT]="0"
 )

Its only show the number of "0" in the table and i want the number of "0" without a "1" on the same DATE 
Thanks and King regards

Comment: Hi @Arthur_75, can you please try the updated code?